# How to make imgObj appear and then disappear to reveal another imgObj?

Tags: canvas, onclick, html5-canvas

I'm new to programming and am trying to make a "proof of concept" project for a game. I'm trying to go from an image I made of a title screen to an image of a room in the game, when the user clicks on the first one, but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. We have to use canvas as part of the assignment so the images are placed in that element. I think I might have it so that the first image I want to see (Obj2) is on top of my second image, but I'm note sure. My console says my imgObj is unidentified. Essentially, I'd like to have imgObj2 appear first and then when the user clicks on it it disappears to reveal imgObj. I'd appreciate any advice or suggestions, thanks!

Here's my code:

```
            <script>

         window.addEventListener("load",eventWindowLoaded, false);
         function eventWindowLoaded() {
            canvasApp();    
         }
         function canvasSupport() {
            return Modernizr.canvas;    
         }
         function canvasApp() {
            if (!canvasSupport()) {
                return; 
            } 
            var theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
            var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");

            //put code here

            var width=1000;
            var height=450;
            var imageObj = new Image();
            var imageObj2 = new Image();

            imageObj2.onload=function(){
            context.drawImage(imageObj2,0,0);
            };

            imageObj2.src='clicktostart.jpg';
            }
            imageObj.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
            };

            imageObj.src = 'insidemansion.jpg';



              </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas drawings (like your title image) cannot be changed once their drawn on the canvas.

Canvas contents are changed by clearing the canvas and redrawing the newly desire contents.

So you can accomplish your task like this

- Preload both images so they are available for drawing
- Draw the title image: context.drawImage(title,0,0);
- Listen for mousedown events (listen for user clicks on the canvas)
- When clicked, clear the canvas: context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
- Draw the room image: context.drawImage(room,0,0);

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

var isDown=false;
var startX;
var startY;

// preload all images
var imgcount=2;
var title=new Image();
title.onload=start;
title.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house6.jpg";
var room=new Image();
room.onload=start;
room.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/inside.jpg";
// call start when each image is fully loaded
function start(){

  // return if all the images aren't yet loaded
  if(--imgcount>0){return;}

  // draw the title image
  ctx.drawImage(title,0,0);

  // listen for mousedown events (clicks)
  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

}

function handleMouseDown(e){

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // clear the canvas and draw the room image  
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.drawImage(room,0,0);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click the mansion image</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=357 height=333></canvas>
```